# Android Google Map V2: Opening info window automatically

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing an Android application that uses google map and so far I got the map and markers created. I've been searching around for a way to open my info windows by default when the map activity starts and I can't seem to find anything for Android Google Map v2.

Are there any functions that does this? Most examples I found are for javascripts.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, its solved, marker.showInfoWindow() was the function I needed